# How to ask stringstream don't split data in quotes (C++)

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm using `std::stringstream` to parse some data from `std::string` value.
This code:

```
std::string str = "data1 data2 data3 \"quotated data\"";
std::stringstream ss(str);
```

If I use `ss >> anotherStr;` I get each word separated by a space.
I don't understand is there an option to ask stringstream to read data in quotes as single string value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `std::quoted` io manipulator is exactly what you need.

A handy reference here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

and a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::string str = "data1 data2 data3 \"quotated data\"";
    std::stringstream ss(str);

    std::string s;
    while (ss >> std::quoted(s))
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
data1
data2
data3
quotated data
```

Comment: Upticked!. I learn something new every day on this site. You Da Man, Richard.